# React: Default Initial State with Prop Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Default Initial State with Prop Value

`activeTab` is held in `TabContext`
I cannot set the default state here because I don't know how to access the prop value of of `Tab` component in a `TabContext` component.

`TabContext.js`

```js
const TabContext = createContext();

export function useTab() {
  return useContext(TabContext);
}

const TabProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState();

  const toggleTab = (title) => {
    setActiveTab(title);
  };

  return (
    <TabContext.Provider value={[activeTab, toggleTab]}>
      {children}
    </TabContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TabProvider;
```

Usage

```js
<TabProvider>
  <TabContainer>
     <Tab title='One' defaultTab/>
     <Tab title='Two' />
  </TabContainer>
</TabProvider>
```

`Tab` component

- `activeTab` state is accessed by `useTab()` hook
- `toggleTab` sets the state to whatever the input is.
- I tried `useEffect()`, but since state changes it creates infinite loop and the activeTab is stuck on the `title` prop of `Tab` Component.

```js
const Tab = ({ title, defaultTab }) => {
  const [activeTab, toggleTab] = useTab();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultTab) {
      toggleTab(title);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={(activeTab === title ? 'text-blue-600' : 'text-gray-900')}
      onClick={() => {
        toggleTab(title);
      }}
    >
      {title}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Desired Outcome:** The `activeTab` default state is the `title` prop value of `Tab` component when it has the prop `defaultTab` while allowing state to be changed afterwards based on click. Also making `defaultTab` prop required for one of the Tab Components under `TabContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Does `Tab` component can have multiple `title` or single value (Like 'One', 'Two') ? If so, it is correct to use `useTab` component in every `Tab` component. And if you are trying to make tab one selected by default you can change ur `Tab` component like below:

```js
const Tab = ({ title, defaultTab }) => {
    const [activeTab, toggleTab] = useTab();
    return (
      <div
        className={(activeTab === title || defaultTab ? 'text-blue-600' : 'text-gray-900')}
        onClick={() => {
          toggleTab(title);
        }}
      >
        {title}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

As I understand you are trying to make any tab selected by default and change the state afterwards.

Comment: This works for only the styling, but I would like the `title` prop of a Tab Component to be used for the default `activeTab` state if the `Tab` Component has the prop `defaultTab`. This is because I have other components relying on this `activeTab` state. Only one `Tab` component can have a `defaultTab` prop at a time. Yes, I want to state to change afterwards.